# Using \ifblank to check more than one parameter

Tags: macros, etoolbox, mathtools

I have been reading through mathtools' docs, and they provide an example that declared a paired delimiter that has a default behaviour if blank, using etoolbox:

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{
    \ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1}
}
```

Then, typing `\norm{x}` gives

[image: image for latex norm]

but typing `\norm{}` gives

[image: second image for latex norm with cdot]

which is pretty handy.

I want to know how this would apply to cases with multiple parameters. For example, suppose I had something simple like:

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inner}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1,#2}
```

Is there a better way than checking all four cases of missing parameters? Or is there a better way?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to add my current approach. At the moment, I have

```latex
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inner}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{
    \ifblank{#1}{\:\cdot\:}{#1},
    \ifblank{#2}{\:\cdot\:}{#2}
}
```

I am not sure this feels right, but I am not experienced enough to know any better. Hence I am hoping to reach out on what would be the better approach.

Comment: " all four cases of missing parameters?" 4?? there are only 2 and as you want to separately test each and use cdot I am not sure what else you could do but have 2 tests?

Comment: you have 4 cases only if you want to condition the insertion of the `,` to one or both of the arguments being empty

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I meant that because it is a two-parameter command, either one could be missing, both could be missing, or neither could be missing, which is four cases, which I wasn't certain how it would be best handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is right, but you can dispense with `etoolbox`, because the current LaTeX kernel has `\IfBlankTF` for the same purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\blank}{\:{\cdot}\:}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inner}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{%
  \IfBlankTF{#1}{\blank}{#1},\IfBlankTF{#2}{\blank}{#2}%
}


\begin{document}

\[
\inner{}{}+\inner{a}{}+\inner{}{b}+\inner{a}{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

I suggest using an abstraction `\blank` command, so you can later change your mind about how to represent a void argument.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice and feedback. I did not know about \IfBlankTF, so this is interesting to know. Very much appreciated.